# Create struct in C/Rust code for Node-FFI

Tags: javascript, node.js, c, rust, ffi

I am trying to return a struct from a Rust function to Node.js, the struct is nested, and contains an array so it is sufficiently complicated that I want to do the allocation in Rust and have Node.JS receive a complete object, here's the Rust code in short:

A `State` is returned that contains a number of `Config`s, a message (e.g error message, or some warning) and a number of configs.

```rust
use std::ffi::CStr;
use std::os::raw::c_char;

#[derive(Debug)]
#[repr(C)]
pub struct Config {
    pub some_fields_here: String,
    // pub ...
}

#[derive(Debug)]
#[repr(C)]
pub struct State {
    pub message: String, // Even changing this to *mut c_char doesn't help the immediate problem
    pub configs: *mut Config,
    pub num_configs: usize,
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn config_from_file(_not_really_used_in_example: *const c_char) -> *mut Configuration {
    let mut configs: Vec<Config> = vec![];
    configs.push(Config {
      some_fields_here: String::from("hello world"), // should maybe be CString::from(...).into_raw()
    });
    Box::into_raw(Box::new(State {
        message: String::from("a message here"),
        configs: Box::into_raw(configs.into_boxed_slice()) as *mut Config,
        num_configs: 1,
    }))
}
```

From the Node side, all the examples and docs we have found only make use of the `StructType` for preparing something to pass into the FFI, or to transparently pass around without ever interrogating it.

What we'd like to do is this:

```js
var ffi = require("ffi-napi");
var ref = require("ref-napi");
var StructType = require("ref-struct-di")(ref);
var ArrayType = require("ref-array-di")(ref);

const Config = StructType({
  some_fields_here: ref.types.CString,
});

const State = StructType({
  message: ref.types.CString,
  configs: ref.refType(ArrayType(Config)),
  num_configs: ref.types.size_t,
});

const StatePtr = ref.refType(StatePtr);

var ourlib = ffi.Library("./target/debug/ourlib", {
  config_from_file: [StatePtr, [ref.types.CString]],
});

const ffiResult = ourlib.config_from_file("a file path, in the real code");
console.log(ffiResult)
// => <Buffer@0x47ce560 20 e2 83 04 00 00 00 00 57 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 57 00 00 00 00 00 00 00, 
type: { [Function: StructType] defineProperty: [Function: defineProperty], toString: [Function: 
toString], fields: { message: [Object], configs: [Object], num_configs: [Object] }, size: 24, 
alignment: 8, indirection: 1, isPacked: false, get: [Function: get], set: [Function: set] }>
```

Here, we need to get a Javscript object something like the struct above, access
to any fields, or see it as an object. We didn't find appropriate examples in the tests or documentation of https://tootallnate.github.io/ref, nor in https://github.com/node-ffi-napi/ref-struct-di

I don't expect to have a clean pass-thru from the C objects backed by `Buffer()` into JavaScript, of course we have to decode and move around things, but I cannot find *any* way to access the information contained within that struct from JavaScript. No combination of any `deref()` or `toObject()` or getting individual fields seems to help at all.

I expected that something like this might do it, but it either/or seg faults or prints garbage depending on some minor tweaks I make one way or another:

```
console.log(ffiResult);
console.log(ref.deref().readCString(ffiResult, 0));
```

I know to some extent doing the allocation in the library, and unpacking these structs in the host language is unidiomatic, but because of the shape of the data, and that we cannot change the library code, we don't have much choice.

Comment: Did you look at [neon](https://docs.rs/neon/0.8.0/neon/)?

Comment: Indeed, we solved this problem, and your prompting reminds me to come back and answer my own question. In short though, no we didn't becuase we're targeting FFI specifically because our thing needs to work from Ruby, Node.js and Python (and, others). Neon is a NAPI binding generator just between Node and Rust so didn't fit our needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and contains an array so it is sufficiently complicated that I want to do the allocation in Rust and have Node.JS receive a complete object,

Containing an array was the tricky/trap part. Arrays in C (ergo FFI) tend to be zero terminated, but there's no guarantee that things work a particular way for arrays of structs.

Here's what we had to do:

1. In Rust, expose a struct with a length member, and a pointer to a single item.
2. In Rust, allocate a vector of our things and use [`into_boxed_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) to forget it, this gives a pointer to the first one.
3. Fill the length property on our struct

Everything like in the example we posted first.

In node.js however it's a bit different, the working code was nearly identical to what we had, here's the types:

```js
const Config = StructType({
  some_fields_here: ref.types.CString,
});

const State = StructType({
  message: ref.types.CString,
  configs: ArrayType(Config), // we had refType(ArrayType(Config))
  num_configs: ref.types.size_t,
});

const StatePtr = ref.refType(StatePtr);

var ourlib = ffi.Library("./target/debug/ourlib", {
  config_f...
```

With that change made, the only thing is that the array is unusable until the length is initialized, so later we simply had to do this:

```
const ffiResult = ourlib.config_from_file("a file path, in the real code");
const ffiState = ffiResult.deref(); // it's a pointer, remember.
ffiState.configs.length = ffiState.num_configs; // see comment below
```

After setting the length of the `ArrayType` then it can be used more or less just like a normal array.

The kicker was [this commit (`dc0d7296`) from about a decade ago!](https://github.com/node-ffi-napi/ref-array-di/commit/dc0d72961da49bf5a5140542578c76610f5e0089).